Why std::fstream::write() modifies tellg()?
Executing the following code
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::fstream fs{"/dev/shm/test.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc};
    std::cerr << "open: "<<  fs.is_open()
              << " good: " << fs.good()
              << " tellg: "<< fs.tellg()
              << " tellp: " << fs.tellp() 
              << std::endl;
    
    // writes "12" in binary
    fs.write("123", 2);

    std::cerr << "open: "<<  fs.is_open()
              << " good: " << fs.good()
              << " tellg: "<< fs.tellg()
              << " tellp: " << fs.tellp() 
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Prints
open: 1 good: 1 tellg: 0 tellp: 0
open: 1 good: 1 tellg: 2 tellp: 2

Why does tellg() change? Shouldn't tellg() still be 0 since I have not performed any reads?

Just a random snipe from the darkened woods: std::cerr is not buffered at all, your std::endl is already doing all the flushing you want, use std::clog and get the same result but with almost 90% fewer system calls.

In the case of std::fstream, it holds a joint file buffer representing both the get and put area respectively. The position indicator that marks the current position in the file is affected by both input and output operations.
As a result of this, in order to perform I/O correctly on a bidirectional stream, when you perform a read after a write or vice-versa, the stream should be repositioned back with seekg or seekp.

Right.  It is POSSIBLE to have streams derive from things other than files, and in that case there might actually be two separate pointers.  That's not the case for streams based on filebuf.

Once again, C++ amazes me. Thank you David.
